# How can I get child elements by element name with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, nested-loops

I have an XML file with many  nodes that look just like this:

```
<map-item>
            <location-name>U Lot (Pine Sreet)</location-name>
            <link>https://maps.google.com?daddr=Pine+Avenue+Middletown+CT+06457</link>
            <latitude>41.5501724</latitude>
            <longitude>-72.6588056</longitude>
            <icon-path>img/parking-icon.svg</icon-path>
 </map-item>
```

I've successfully looped through all the of the **map-item** elements in the XML file like this:

```
 markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("map-item");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              //do something here for each marker
        }
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to drill down and get at the child elements inside of each map-item element, such as **location-name** or **icon-path**.  What do I need to do in order to grab the values of those child elements and do something with them?

Comment: Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwnrrngv/)..

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your problem you should upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) again, on each marker. If the xml is valid and conforms to some schema, you can expect that there is at least one element of the given name in your `<marker>`.

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("map-item");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var marker = markers[i];
    var locationName = marker.getElementsByTagName("location-name")[0].textContent;
    var iconPath = marker.getElementsByTagName("icon-path")[0].textContent;
    …
}
```

If you don't know how many child elements will be there in each `<marker>`, you'll have to switch on the `.length` of the selected list or loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `markers[0].childNodes`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
  // NOTE: List is live, Adding or removing children will change the list
  markers[0].childNodes[i];
}
```

See [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

@Prasanth has been kind enough to demonstrate with a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwnrrngv/1/) to demonstrate (I modified the output so it wouldn't be an alert).